# CSS mix-blend-mode breaks when translating parent element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, mix-blend-mode

I'm encountering an issue with CSS mix-blend-mode, where the mix-blend-mode is lost when I apply a translation transformation to the parent element. I'm seeking a solution to maintain the mix blend mode effect during the translation.

The issue arises when I apply a transform, such as transform: translateX(20px);, to the parent div. Once this translation is applied, the text no longer blends with the background image as intended.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const marquee = document.querySelector(".marque");
  marquee.classList.add("move");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);

  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marque {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 10s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.marque.move {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.title-link {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
  will-change: transform;
}

.title-link:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: initial;
  color: blue;
}

.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;

  /* Add styles for dynamic text sizing and hover color change */
}

.background-marque {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
}

.selected-pic {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cover-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="marque">
      <a class="title-link">
        <h3 class="title" id="title1">Title One</h3>
      </a>
      <a class="title-link">
        <h3 class="title" id="title2">Title Two</h3>
      </a>
      <a class="title-link">
        <h3 class="title" id="title3">Title Three</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="background-marque">

      <img class="cover-image" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XkviAtJ1s6Q/T3YFb2RUhDI/AAAAAAAAAVQ/EHomLZlFMKo/s1600/small+cat.jpg" alt="Cat Image">

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Expected Behavior:** The text should maintain its mix-blend-mode effect with the image during and after the translation.
**Actual Behavior:** The mix-blend-mode effect is lost as soon as the translation is applied.

I have tried looking at the solution in this example, where you apply the blend mode to the parent, but then I lose the ability to hover each item to remove its blend move individually [Mix-blend-mode doesn't work if I use "transform" on the parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537280/mix-blend-mode-doesnt-work-if-i-use-transform-on-the-parent-div)

Is there a way to maintain the mix-blend-mode 'difference' effect on text during a translation transformation of its parent div? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mix-blend-mode doesn't work if I use "transform" on the parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537280/mix-blend-mode-doesnt-work-if-i-use-transform-on-the-parent-div)

Comment: I tried adding the blend mode to the container, but it doesn't work in my instance as it removes the effect of being able to hover and remove blend mode on each item.